# Python rewrite the code to become more elegantly

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python from R. They are quite different. I wrote a python code to deal with Excel file. The code was running well, but I think it's kind of the style of R. I want somebody to show me writing the code in python way.

The data structure looks like:

```
      Name     Details
1     AAA      first(100%-8)
2     BBB      first(50%-8),second(50%-8)
3     CCC      sixth(30%-8),seventh(60%-7),first(10%-7.75)
4     DDD      third(100%-6)
5     EEE      fifth(70%-7.5),second(30%-7.5)
6     FFF      first(70%-8),ninth(30%-6.75)
...   ...      ..........
```

As you can see, Mr.first gave Mr.AAA 8 points with 100% weights. Otherwise, in the 2nd,3rd,6th row, Mr.first gave different peoples with different scores. So the average scores that Mr.first gave is (8+8+7.75+8)/4 = 7.94, which is the average score of his group.

What I am looking for is: for the Mr.AAA, his final score is not 8 * 100%，it's 
8 * (7.5/7.94)*100%, where 7.5 is a constant and 7.94 is the average score of the group of Mr.first. Similarly, for the Mr.BBB, his final score is 
 8 * (7.5/7.94)*50% + 8 * (7.5/7.75)*50%. Hope you get it.

So, question is pretty simple.

My code:

```
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import xlrd
import re
data = xlrd.open_workbook(filename)   #read the data
table = data.sheets()[0]              #read the sheet
nrows = table.nrows                   #get the number of total rows
regr = r'[\u4e00-\u9fa5a-zA-Z]+' # regular expression for CHN and ENG names
regr1 = r'[0-9]+'                # for scores and percentage
score = {}                       # The dict: {AAA:{first:[1.0,8.0]},......}
group = {}                       # The dict: {first:[8,8,7.75,8],......}


for i in range(2,nrows):
   target = table.cell(i,10).value  # the details data [first(100%-8)]
   person = table.cell(i,2).value   # the Name data    [AAA]
   c = target.split(',')            # If in details data there are more than  
                                    # one person, then split them        
   score[person] = {}               # set an empty dict
   for j in c:
         d = re.findall(regr,j)     # get the name 
         d = "".join(d)             # transfer the list to string
         value = re.findall(regr1,j)   #get the score and percentage
         value1 = int(value[0])/100 # get the percentage 
         value2 = '.'.join([x for x in value[1:]])   # get the score
         value2 = float(value2)                      # change to float
         group.setdefault(d,[]).append(value2)       
         score[person].setdefault(d,[value1,value2]) 


#This part is for calculating the group average
for key in group:
   total = 0
   length = len(group[key])
   group[key] = [x for x in group[key]]
   for x in group[key]:
      total = total + x
   group[key] = total/length

output = {}       #set an empty dict to store output: {AAA:7.56,......}

#this part is for calculating the final score
for key in score:
   average = 0
   for subkey in score[key]:
      average = score[key][subkey][0] * score[key][subkey][1] 
                *7.5/group[subkey] + average
      output[key] = average


print(output)                                       #print the output
```

Finally here:   For the reason of secrecy, I can not provide the raw data. But if you need, I can create the raw data. I am here, because I feeling that my code is tedious. I hope someone can help me to write it more elegantly. it's for future work.

Thanks.

Comment: just paste the data and make it a code block dont write html people will think you have data in HTML form

Comment: are you sure your data looks like an HTML table instead of 2d rows and columns?

Comment: you should definetly check [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) and maybe check the [modern pandas](https://tomaugspurger.github.io/modern-1.html) introduction by tom augspurger and also the apply function might be interesting. Additionaly, the split-apply-combine workflow is explained [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html)

Comment: can you flatten your data or rearrange it into a dataframe? Then several operations become more "natural"

Comment: Thanks for your advice, i re-edited it @Vivek Kalyanarangan

Comment: I know "pandas", but unfamiliar with it. I will check it. Thanks for your comment. @Quickbeam2k1

Comment: As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, **try to write a title that summarizes what your code does**, not what you want to get out of a review. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](http://meta.CodeReview.StackExchange.com/a/2438/41243) for guidance on writing good question titles.